# Flutter - The return type 'Null' isn't a 'City', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart

I got an error when I tried to use List.firstWhere and set `orElse` to return null

Error shows: `The return type 'Null' isn't a 'City', as required by the closure's context`

Sample code below

```dart
/// city.dart

class City {
  final int id;
  final String no;
  final String name;
  final String website;
  final bool status;

  City(this.id, this.no, this.name, this.website, this.status);

  City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        no = json['no'],
        name = json['name'],
        website = json['website'],
        status = json['status'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {'id': id, 'no': no, 'name': name, 'website': website, 'status': status};
}
```

```dart
/// main.dart

/// declare a list variable
List<City> _cities = [];

...


_cities.firstWhere((element) => element.id == 1, orElse: () => null); // error here
```

Though I can use `firstWhereOrNull` method in `package:collection` and won't get any error, I want to figure out how to use firstWhere in a correct way.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its throw error because you declare the list is `non-null` value.

if we look into the function we can see the different between them.

- firsWhereOrNull ( package:collection )

as you can see, the T? is nullable by default. so its will return null

```
T? firstWhereOrNull(bool Function(T element) test) {
    for (var element in this) {
      if (test(element)) return element;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

---

- firstWhere
  its non-null value.
  data type of `orElse` is following based on our declared value.
  since you declare `List<City>` this is non-null value,

then when you set function
`orElse: () => null` it will `throw IterableElementError.noElement();`

```
 E firstWhere(bool test(E element), {E orElse()?}) {
    for (E element in this) {
      if (test(element)) return element;
    }
    if (orElse != null) return orElse();
    throw IterableElementError.noElement();
  }
```

but if you declare `List<City?>` the `E` in firstWhere now is nullable value.
then it will no error.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return `null` because it is expected that method will return the instance of `City` class, which is not `nullable`.

You have 2 solutions:

1. You can declare the `_cities` list as `List<City?>` (list of nullable City).
   Then method `firstWhere` can return `null` but you should take care about `null safety`, e.g: while calling element.
2. Other way is to create a `empty City`, so in the `City` class create the static field:

.

```
static const empty = City(
    id: 0,
    no: '',
    name: '',
    website: '',
    status: false,
  );
```

then you can return this `empty City`.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you cannot use 'firstWhere' directly, the right way to use the method...
`_cities.map((element) => element.id).firstWhere((elementId) => elementId == 1, orElse: () => null);`